# accessing rss feeds with jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to learn ajax via jquery, and am running into problems accessing rss feeds. The error handler returns stuff I can't begin to comprehend, but readyState comes back 0, and response text is empty. But when I check with fiddler, it says the response is encoded and offers option to decode. After clicking to decode, I can preview the correctly returned xml.

Is this a cross domain issue or something else? I don't understand why there would be issues retrieving data across domains for a public RSS feed.

Thank you!

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.tmz.com/rss.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: xmlParser,
    error: function (xml) {
        $.each(xml, function (key, value) {
            alert(key + ": " + value);
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Please create jsfiddle to reproduce your problem and describe the error / expected outcome

Comment: No real expected outcome, this is more for educational purposes. Did I do this fiddle correctly? http://jsfiddle.net/wJXqK/1/

Comment: Please use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`

Comment: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access` You can't access that XML from jsfiddle. Do this on your local machine.

Comment: Update for console log, sorry. http://jsfiddle.net/wJXqK/2/. I'm actually preparing for a job interview where cross site scripting is a huge factor, so if the site (TMZ in this instance) does not have the Access-Control header mentioned above, I cannot access?

Answer (score 0):

It could be problem in the way you are interpreting the ajax error. The latest Jquery version error callback parameters are:

```
Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
```

Probably you would want to do

```
error: function(jqXHR) {
  alert(jqXHR.responseXML);
}
```

Please read the API doc: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

Comment: Hi gerrytan. This unfortunately just returns null, I'm using jQuery 1.11.1 if that matters?